# const_cast rules in c++

Tags: c++, constants, shared-ptr, const-cast

```
struct foo
{
    const int A;
    int B;
    foo() : A(10), B(20) {}
};

void main()
{
    foo f1;
    const_cast<int&>(f1.A) = 4; //line 1
    const foo f2;
    const_cast<int&>(f2.B) = 4; //line 2
}
```

Do both line 1 and 2 exhibit undefined behaviour? Would the behavior be different if `f1` and `f2` were `shared_ptr` of types listed in code above?

Comment: It does not matter what data type is loosing constness, problem is compiler can assume that object does not change and produce relevant code.

Answer (score 15):

The behaviour both `const_cast<int&>(f1.A) = 4` *and* `const_cast<int&>(f2.B) = 4` are *undefined*.

If an object is originally defined as `const`, and you cast away that `const`-ness *and* attempt to modify the object, the behaviour is *undefined*.

Comment: @YSC: Hum. Could've sworn `f2` was non-`const` originally. Still, only a little edit needed. Thanks.

Comment: Edits making non-const object now const (even _sneaky_ edits made on Fridays) are welcome. I wish there was more of them at work.

Comment: As an addendum, if an object is originally non-const, and then passed through a const pointer or const reference, and then `const_cast` back to non-const, I believe that is well-defined behavior.  But, in my opinion, it is still a bad code smell to `const_cast` away const-ness even if the developer KNOWS it is a non-const object really really.

Comment: @Eljay: Yes you are correct, both factually and stylistically. It's only if you attempt to modify the object do you get undefined results.

Comment: @Eljay there's the school of thought for de-duplicating getter's of the style `class Foo { const Bar& do_get() const { /* single impl */ } public: Bar& get() { return const_cast<Bar&>(do_get()); } const Bar& get() const { return do_get(); } };`